# Python Numpy Array Operator x += y Different From x = x + y?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I run the code below:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([1, 1, 1])
u_list = [v]

for i in range(2):
  v += np.array([i, i, i])
  u_list.append(v)

return u_list
```

Returns `[array([2, 2, 2]), array([2, 2, 2]), array([2, 2, 2])]`

But if I run the same code, with the 5th line as `v = v + np.array([i, i, i])` it returns `[array([1, 1, 1]), array([1, 1, 1]), array([2, 2, 2])]`

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v +=` changes the array inplace

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([1, 1, 1])
u_list = [v]

print(id(v))
for i in range(2):
    v += np.array([i, i, i])
    u_list.append(v)
    print(id(v))
```

prints:

```
4460459392
4460459392
4460459392
```

All arrays have the same id, hence it is only one array you reference three times.

`v = v +` makes a new array:

```
v = np.array([1, 1, 1])
u_list = [v]

print(id(v))
for i in range(2):
    v = v + np.array([i, i, i])
    u_list.append(v)
    print(id(v))
```

prints:

```
4462915792
4462918592
4462919072
```

The arrays have different ids. Therefore, they are different objects.